# Java: implementing a stack( pile) with ArrayList working with different types

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

I'm building two classes: `class Stack` which implements a stack using `ArrayList` with `get` and `remove`, and `class Test2` which uses `Stack` to create stacks of chosen(in `Test2`) variables. In my example, I chose strings, but I'd like it to work with different types as well.

These are the classes:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Stack{
  ArrayList pila;

  public void push(Object o) {
        pila.add(o);
    }
  public Object pop() {
        if (!pila.isEmpty())
            return pila.remove(pila.size()-1);
      else return null;
  }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test2{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String a = "mario";
    String b = "luigi";
    String c = "tony";
    Stack s = new Stack();
    s.pila = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.push(a);
    s.push(b);
    s.push(c);
    for (int i=0; i <3; i++) System.out.println(s.pop());
  }
}
```

It is working but it gives me the following warning when I compile `Stack`, and I wonder if this was the right way to do that.

```
Stack.java:6: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a
member of the raw type ArrayList
                 pila.add(o);
                         ^   where E is a type-variable:
     E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
```

Comment: Look up Java Generics. You'll need to make your Stack class generic, just like ArrayLists are.

Comment: And you'd better use `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList` as you always add/remove from the end and do not use access by index.

Comment: And don't use wildcards as in `import java.util.*`, as it's unpredictable which symbols will be added to that package in e.g. Java 12. Use an IDE like Eclipse that can keep track of the necessary imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add generics here. For e.g:

```
Arraylist<T> pila;
```

Where T can be any type.

According to your code, it will accept any type of data but when you want to access it from somewhere else, you will definitely get class cast exception.

You need to be very specific that what type of elements you want to store.